# Equal relation between two terms

Tags: coq

For finding less or equal relation between two numbers (n a).I have used the following two commands.But I have problem ,when apply these commands
for equal relation betwen two terms(n 0). Secondly if value of function(f1) is greater or equal to zero,is true,then we can write equal relation between f1 and zero will be true?

```
 destruct (le_lt_dec n a).
rewrite (leb_correct _ _ l).
rewrite (leb_correct_conv _ _ l).

 destruct (eq_dec n 0).
 rewrite (eqb_correct _ _ l).
 rewrite (eqb_correct_conv _ _ l).

 (0<=?f1)=true ->
 (0=?f1)=true.
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware that the statement `(0 <=? f1) = true -> (0 =? f1) = true` is not true, in general.  It is falsified when `f1` is `1` for example.

Maybe you wanted to prove the following statement?

```
forall f1, (f1 <=? 0) = true -> (f1 =? 0) = true
```

If you load the `Arith` library, you will find a theorem named `Ǹat.le_0_r` that expresses a similar statement but with `<=` instead of `<=?` and `=` instead of `=?`.  You can use theorems `Nat.eqb_eq` and `Nat.leb_le` to finish the proof.